# interactive video with html5

Tags: html, video, actionscript, canvas

I am new to actionScript programming. I know some html and I am currently learning html5. I need to do an interactive video by putting html content in a specific time of the video. I'll be more concise:

For example, I have a video that is 5 minutes long, let's suppose that from the second 3:50 to 4:00 I need to display two boxes over the video, each one representing one choice. If at  3:50 the video shows the possibility to the viewer to select among two paths (the video told the user to select among those paths for instance) the viewer will have the possibility to select one of the paths by clicking on one of the two boxes that will appear in that time interval. I know this needs to be made with the  tag and with hyperlinks.

My question is How do I tell the html5 video player to display a canvas from the minute 3:50 to the minute 4:00 in which two hyperlinks will display??

Thanks for your attention I will appreciate very much your help. I need some kind of guidance because I have been looking for many days.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case it seems you want to be able to control the video flow of the user through interactions that jump to different times in the video.

Using html5 video player to seek to a different time in a video (using [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)) you could create a click event on a box that you lay on top of the video and set the time when you click that box, using:

```
// Jump 30 seconds into the video
var time = '30';
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = "video.mp4";

// Set the time
video.currentTime = time;
video.play();
```

You can check out how we created an [interactive video authoring tool](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-interactive-video/tree/master/scripts)(open source) using html5 and JS and use that.

If you don't want to spend time coding an interactive video you should check out H5Ps authoring tool through this [simple example](https://h5p.org/interactive-video). You can test out creating your own at [H5P.org](https://h5p.org/node/add/h5p-content) as well. The tool is completely free.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe that you mean javascript instead of actionscript. If that is the case then I would definitely check this out [Video.JS](http://videojs.com/docs/api/).
When you reach the current time you trigger your method/function which adds whatever you want on top of the video.

> var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();

However, if you DO mean actionscript then you are working with a flash player. Therefore I suggest you take a look at this  [Vimeo Player](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/as-api)

> currentTime:Number [read-only] Returns the current playback time of the video.